# z-index issue in ie7 with fixed header element and transparency

Tags: css, z-index, opacity, gradient, 960.gs

I've mocked up a page using 960.gs that has has several elements fixed in a div under which the content of the of the page is to flow. The background of this div is a CSS gradient, and has a height of 100% (if the gradient is applied to to the actual body of the page it doesn't actually extend the whole width of the page). As the user scrolls up, the content is to be viewable behind an opaque menu.

http://resume.jamesfishwick.com/

The layout works as I want in FF and Chrome, but the content of the page scrolls over the fixed upper area in IE7.

I understand that a new stacking context is being created, but I've been unable to resolve this by fiddling with the z-index of the elements in question, or their parents. I know I can consolidate some of the extra divs used by the grid, but I've been unable to do so in a way that keeps the gradient and transparency effects.

How can I achieve this look in IE7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IE7 an element is trapped by its positioned parent and cannot escape. One cannot interweave the children of positioned parents because ie7 and 6 incorrectly apply a z-index of zero to positioned elements when they should have applied auto.

There is no way to escape this other than not positioning the parent which my case is not possible because I want it fixed.

So I'll need to change the design and apply the gradient to another element and not the 100% high fixed element. That will allow the header to be separate form the content and then the content can go under the header.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to give that scrolling div a z-index which is less than the z-index on the main header. To control the transparency for msie 7 just add the following css code to the end of your document say right before the </body> tag.

```
/* ie6 hack */
* html .gradientLayer { filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='/path_to_images/mygradient.png', sizingMethod='scale')); }
/* ie7 hack */
*+ html .gradientLayer { filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='/path_to_images/mygradient.png', sizingMethod='scale')); }
```

Comment: That div doesn't really scroll (I mean, not on its own), its just not fixed; you're just looking at the native page scroll. 

Can you tell me exactly what CSS I need to add to fix the issue? If I give a z-index to "#content" that is less than the various header elements (which I just added to my original), nothing is resolved because of the new stacking context of "#content." If I out right give "#upper" a z-index it completely obscures the content (e.g. http://resume.jamesfishwick.com/index2.html).

And the opacity and gradients are already in place; don't need help with that.